# How can I use rsample for multiple mrl algorithms?

Tags: r, mlr, resample

I have some difficulty using the function `resample` of **mlr** package, in my case for example.

```r
library(mlr)

learners = makeLearners(cls = c("C50", "rpart","ada","naiveBayes"), type = "classif", predict.type = "prob")

data_task = makeClassifTask(data = dataset, target = "y_dx")

repCV = makeResampleDesc(method = "RepCV", folds = 5 ,stratify = TRUE)
valCV = resample(
    learners = learners, 
    task = data_task, 
    resampling = repCV, 
    measures = list(mmce, acc, auc))
```

when running the variable valCV, it generates the following error

> Error in checkLearner(learner) :
> argument "learner" is missing, with no default

The problem is that it **doesn't recognize the learners argument**, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `mlr3`. I get a warning message while loading the package mlr `Warning message: 'mlr' is in 'maintenance-only' mode since July 2019. Future development will only happen in 'mlr3'.. Due to the focus on 'mlr3' there might be uncaught bugs meanwhile in {mlr} - please
consider switching.`

Comment: hi @akrun , the package mlr3 It has other functions that I don't know about but I'll check it out, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resample()` takes only a single learner -- did you mean to use [`benchmark()`](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/benchmark_experiments.html)?

```
benchmark(
  learners = learners, 
  task = data_task, 
  resampling = repCV, 
  measures = list(mmce, acc, auc))
```

And as the comment points out, you should switch to mlr3. See the [book chapter on evaluation and benchmark experiments](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/performance.html).

Comment: ohh, thanks. I have a question, can autoplot be used in this case?

Comment: In mlr3 you can.